# Who was the first common person to figure out Batman's identity?

Tags: dc, batman

Batman is famously secretive about his identity, but I remember Coleman Reese from *The Dark Knight* figured it out.

So who was the first common person to figure out Batman's real identity?

By "common person", I mean people excluding supervillains, known associates of Batman, and other superheroes.

Comment: First in- or out-of-universe?

Comment: Do women count as well?

Comment: @Laurel,in universe obviously

Comment: @Adamant, no they aren't smart enough ,  just kidding ofc they do count

Comment: Probably "common person" would be more clear, then. Or even more clear, "ordinary/normal person."

Comment: Does Coleman Reese actually count, per your stipulations? He was an employee of Wayne Enterprises, and therefore an associate of Bruce Wayne in a sense.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can think of Silver St. Cloud in the late '70s who figured it out. She and Bruce Wayne were romantically involved, and there was a dramatic scene where she was watching Batman and the Joker fighting. She realized then who Batman was.

Comment: @LogicDictates, In the question i mentioned known associates of Batman not Bruce Wayne, these are two different things

Comment: How do you feel about a person who did not wear a mask or any type of fancy costume, and didn't have any superpowers or unusual weapons, but was part of a criminal gang that fought Batman while working for The Joker? So that person was not what we normally mean by "supervillain," but could reasonably be called "one of a supervillain's henchpersons who figured out Batman's big secret." As you might guess, I have a candidate from a long time ago who fits that description, but I don't want to waste time typing out a full answer if this doesn't qualify as the right type of "common person" for you.

Answer (score 4):

In the story "When Batman was Robin" (Detective comics 226  12-1955) there was a detective named Harvey Harris, who was kind of a mentor to young Bruce Wayne.  Bruce appeared to him wearing a Robin costume and learned the methodology of detecting from him.  He deduced Bruce's identity and. later, when Dick Grayson (Robin) came on the scene, Harris knew that young Bruce had grown up to become Batman.